# CakePHP 2, how to AuthComponent::login() with plain-text password?

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0

I would like to implement CakePHP 2 website over existing database with plain-text password field.

This is my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
      'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
      'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'),
      'authError' => 'You cannot view this page',
      'authorize' => array('Controller'),
      'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
          'userModel' => 'User',
          'fields' => array('username' => 'user_id', 'password' => 'user_password')
        )
      )
    )
  ); 

  public function isAuthorized($user) {
    return true;
  }

  function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('home');
    //$this->Auth->authenticate = $this->User;

    parent::beforeFilter();
  }
```

This is my UserController.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
  public $paginate = array(
    'fields' => array('user_id', 'user_desc', 'user_password'),
    'limit' => 25,
    'order' => array(
      'user_id' => 'asc'
    )
  );

  function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Cannot Login');  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my User model

```
class User extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'User';
  public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
  public $belongsTo = 'Group'; 
}
```

According to those files above, when I pressed the Login button on login.ctp, I saw

> select * from users where user_password = 'this_is_hashing_password'

on the sql dump section.

So, how to turn-off the automatic hashing algorithm, so the login() will compare the user input to the database stored password as plain-text???

I have tried lots of reading on the CakePHP book but I cannot find any, also using hashPasswords($data) technique which found from the internet is not working.

Please help.
Kongthap.

Comment: why are you storing unhashed passwords?

Comment: yeah, that should cost you your job! sry, mate, but that really is a no go. No help from me on this own , either. I will not participate in this crime.

Comment: you should never have unhashed passwords

Answer (score 2):

The best answer **really is** to batch-process your stored passwords so they are hashed, however there are cases where you may be adding a Cake app to an existing application that hashes passwords differently (say by not hashing them at all), so the question is valid even if the goal in this case is not.

Try these resources for modifying Cake's password hashing function, depending on your Cake version:

- [Cake 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords)
- [Cake 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html#change-hash-function)

Answer (score 0):

I got plain text password working in `Cakephp 3`, this should only be use for **DEVELOPMENT** purpose, you should never store password in plain text in production.

That being said, during development, plain text password allows me to focus on login instead of implementing a fully functional user encrypt/decrypt logic. Which is going to be replaced by an OAuth / SAML module anyway...

OK here comes the source code:

#### ROOT/src/Auth/PlainTextPasswordHasher.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\AbstractPasswordHasher;
/**
 * Plain text password for demo use, DO NOT PUSTH THIS TO PROD
*/
class PlainTextPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher
{

    public function hash($password)
    {
        return $password;
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword)
    {
        return $password === $hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

#### ROOT/src/Controller/PagesController.php

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password',
                    ],
                    'passwordHasher' => [
                        'className' => 'PlainText',
                    ],
                    'userModel' => 'YourUsers',
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Logins',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Source: This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eASSNS1f3V4 and this section of the official doc:  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes